# iOS app crashes when using CircleProgress cn1lib

Tags: codenameone

My iOS App crashes when showing a form in which I used the CircleProgress cn1lib. Again on Android this is working fine from the beginning.

I reduced the code using CircleProgress to

```
CircleProgress cp = new CircleProgress();
cp.setProgress(progress);
```

This is invoked in a for-loop for several rows inside a TableLayout container.
Everything works fine if the code is commented and hence not in use.

#### Update 1

I still don't know where the error popped up in xcode exactly, but:

@steve hannah:
I found the error by myself: The app crashes if the progress is set to 0.

Hence, this solved my issue:

```
if(progress > 0)
   cp.setProgress(0);
```

By not setting the progress it'll display the CircleProgress with progress 0 by default.

#### Update 2:

Issue is fixed now.
[Issue on github](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/CN1CircleProgress/issues/1)

Comment: If you have a reproducible crash in xcode can you include the stack trace from xcode?

Comment: I created a test case based on what you describe but I can't seem to reproduce the problem.  If you can generate a small test case and post it to the CN1 issue tracker I'll take a look.   The only thing that comes to mind that might cause this is doing something with the UI off the EDT.  Make sure you're on the EDT for UI operations.

Comment: Hi Shai, I added stack trace produced by the xcode-"bt"-command. Hi Steve, I do not spawn threads anywhere, now I included "Display.getInstance().isEdt()" right before I call the CircleProgress constructor. I'll try to generate a small test case.

Comment: The _isEdt()-method returns "true" every time I am creating the CircleProgress. It's called 5 times for 5 CircleProgresses in the form within a for-loop

Comment: Can you include the stack traces of the other threads as well? I want to see where they are stuck with specific focus on where the EDT is stuck.